# Highcharts: Position scatter plot in a multi-series column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Using Highcharts 3.0: If I have a column chart with multiple series, how can I position a scatter plot on top so that each dot in the scatter plot is placed on top of one certain column, and not just between them? [Example jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sas5g/1/):

```
chart: {
     type: "column"   
},
series: [
    {
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        data: [2, 4, 6]
    },
    {
        type: "scatter",
        data: [1,4,3]
    }
]
```

Could I for instance have the scatter dots (series 3) drawn so that they are visually related to series 1, and not series 2?

PS: I would like to be able to relate the scatter plot to the columns on a "per category basis", meaning that I do not only want to be able to consequently shift all the scatter points x pixels to the left/right. I would for instance like to be able to relate the first and third scatter dots to series 1, and the second scatter dot to series 2.

Is this possible with highcharts? Hope the question was understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have found to do this is by using decimal values as the x value:

```
data: [[-.15,1],[-.15,4],[.15,3]]
```

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sas5g/3/

Comment: That does work, but I am a bit concerned if this is doable when I have a dynamic number of series and categories. Seems difficult to accurately calculate the offsets on-the-fly..?

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that the scatter plot will not be correctly positioned anymore when hiding one of the column series (by clicking the legend).

Comment: Yes, all very true.  I know that this has been a long running question, so there may be better solutions out there - I haven't seen them myself.  It would be worth looking through the feature requests, as I know the issue has come up there as well:  http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general